# const variables may not be used in a constant expression?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, constant-expression

**Why is this C code illegal in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?**

```
const unsigned int x = 64;
char resultBufNative[x+1];
```

It gives `error C2057: expected constant expression`.

---

### Original question

I'm completely baffled by this one.

Relevant function:

```
jstring Java_com_nabto_api_NabtoCApiWrapper_nabtoGetSessionToken(JNIEnv* env, jclass thiz, jobject sessionObj)
{
    const size_t size = 64;
    char resultBufNative[size+1];

    size_t resultLen;

    //Get the session
    nabto_handle_t session;
    session = (nabto_handle_t) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, sessionObj);

    nabto_status_t nabtoStatus = nabtoGetSessionToken(session, resultBufNative, size, &resultLen);

    if (nabtoStatus == NABTO_OK && resultLen <= size) {
        // Terminate char array, convert to java string, free buffer and return result
        resultBufNative[resultLen] = 0;
        jstring result = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, resultBufNative);
        //nabtoFree(resultBufNative);
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Error message: `error C2057: expected constant expression`

On line `char resultBufNative[size+1];`

To me, that makes the relevant code as such:

```
    const size_t size = 64;
    char resultBufNative[size+1];
```

And apparently, `const size_t + 1` is not a constant expression.

There are no defines or macros `size` dicking about (replacing it with xyzabc gives the same error). `size_t` is defined as `typedef unsigned int __w64 size_t` when I mouseover `size_t` in my IDE (Visual Studio Ultimate 2013).

After the C2057 expected constant expression error, the compiler gives 2 more errors:

```
C24166: cannot allocate array of size 0
C2133: 'resultBufNative': unknown size
```

For the same line of code. Naturally, these are because it doesn't know what `size + 1` is, so it becomes 0.

Using

```
    constexpr const size_t size = 64;
    char resultBufNative[size+1];
```

Gives `error C2065: 'constexpr' : undeclared identifier`.

Using

```
    const size_t size = 65;
    char resultBufNative[size];
```

Gives `error C2057: expected constant expression`.

Using

```
    static const size_t size = 64;
    char resultBufNative[size+1];
```

Gives `error C2057: expected constant expression`.

Using

```
    const unsigned int x = 64;
    char resultBufNative[x+1];
```

Gives `error C2057: expected constant expression`.

I guess what I want to do is not supported.

Comment: Try `constexpr const size_t size = 64`

Comment: use `static const` or `constexpr`

Comment: @leemes `constexpr const size_t size = 64` gives `C2065: 'constexpr' unknown identifier`

Comment: Then your compiler is not C++11 compatible, and you have to settle for `static const` as suggested by @TonyD. Oh, and you don't need *both* `constexpr` and `const`.

Comment: I'm using C - I got two projects mixed up. The code is ported from an android NDK JNI wrapper, with all the android references stripped out.

Comment: `const size_t size = 64;` --> `enum { size = 64 };`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that works, but looks terribly evil. Why does that work, and `const unsigned int x = 64` not?

Comment: @Pimgd `x` is not a constant because it is variable in C. VS2013 does not support the VLA.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is that in some spec somewhere?

Comment: @Pimgd yes, VS2013 supports some C99,  but it is  C89(C90)+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C89 mode, the array size must be a compile time constant but `size` is not one. `const` keyword means *read only*, not compile time constant (this is different in C++). So you have few options here:

1) Compile in C99 mode which supports VLAs.

2) Use fixed size arrays:

```
   char resultBufNative[64+1];
```

3) Use

```
#define size 64
```

which is basically same as option (2) except preprocessor does that replacement for you.

4) Use `enum` as suggested by bluepixy, which is a compile time constant unlike `const`.

Comment: Hmm... how do I compile in C99?

Comment: If you are using GCC or clang, it would be: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall file.c` / `clang -std=c99 -Wall file.c`.

Comment: I wish I was using gcc =). Looking around the internet and the comments here, it seems I'll have to use the hacky workarounds since VS doesn't have C99. I wish Visual Studio supported C99.

Comment: 5) `char *resultBufNative = malloc(size + 1);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY then I'll have to check for NULL, and I'd rather not.

Comment: @Pimgd I'd prefer `enum` in C89 as it's both compile time constant and type safe. It's not hacky at all.

Comment: @BlueMoon from a syntactical perspective, I get your point, but I prefer to use enums for enumerations, and not things like constant array sizes. I'll use that, though.

Comment: VS2015 is supposed to support C99, but I'm not sure how to turn it on

Comment: You can turn it on by compiling as Cpp /Tp

Comment: @tofutim Yes, it now fully supports C99: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx But I have no idea how to turn it on.

Comment: @l3x Project / Properties / Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Advanced / Compile As / "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)"

Answer (score -1):

An updated solution is to compile as C++ using /Tp in Visual Studio 2015. While not perfect, the C++ compiler supports a large subset of C99.